# Javascript is auto deselecting checkboxes in a private messaging system

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good day. 
I m building a private messaging system using jquery ajax to get new messages without reloading the entire  page.
There is a div I gave an id called "inbox_display".
I want this div to be auto reloading using setInterval of 1000ms so that new messages will be displayed without reloading the entire page.

Beside each inbox is a checkbox which will be selected when a message is to be deleted.
The problem I'm encountering now is that whenever any of these checkboxes is selected, the setInterval is auto deselecting those checkbox.

What should I do to stop this?
Thanks

Comment: When new messages arrive, you must be creating new element, but how are you adding it? Can you share some code? Also if you are looping over data every time, you will loose UI state.

Comment: My jquery ajax code is written in a file and the php code that queries the database is written in another file.
So, it's inside the php code that the html code that displays the checkbox is written.        

<input type=’checkbox' value=’$inbox_id' name=’inbox_id'/> $subject 

The above code is written inside a for loop which will be looping through each message when a new message arrives. It works fine, but the setInterval auto deselects any checked checkbox.

Comment: Place the whole your code in your question in order to help you. Otherwise I'm afraid your question is going to be closed :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its resets to default is because you are creating them again. When you create dynamic elements using a loop over data, since you do not have their state, you will reset them to default behavior.

Better solution use `$.append()` function. It will append new element without rerendering others.

#### Sample of Both Cases

```js
var data = [], interval = null, count = 0;

function addCheckbox(){
    var htmlStr = "";
 data.forEach(function(row){
        htmlStr += "<input type='checkbox' value=" +row.value+ ">" +row.label+ "</input><br/>"
    });
    
    $("#dataLoop").html(htmlStr);
}

function appendCheckbox(row){
    var chk = "<input type='checkbox' value=" +row.value+ ">" +row.label+ "</input><br/>"
 $("#UIState").append(chk)
}

function pauseInterval(){
 window.clearInterval(interval);
}

function initInterval(){
 interval = setInterval(function(){
        var _lbl = "Checkbox " + count;
        var row = {label: _lbl, value:""}
     data.push(row);
        addCheckbox();
        appendCheckbox(row);
        count++;
    }, 3000)
}

(function(){
 initInterval();
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
DATA:<br/>
<div id ="dataLoop"></div>

UI State:<br/>
<div id ="UIState"></div>

<button onClick="pauseInterval()">Clear</button>
```